If there is a hole in the main object of the photo and the background is visible inside it (like a ring), rembg cannot remove the bg of that part
I need to remove the background of online jewelry products with python. The background around products such as rings or bracelets is easily removed, but the background of the middle cavity of these objects is not removed. In addition to rembg, I tried several other packages, but I am facing the same problem in all of these packages. Whereas when I use sites like remove.bg, the background is removed correctly.
this is my code
input_image  = Image.open( input_path )
input_array  = np.array( input_image )
output_array = remove( input_array )
output_image = Image.fromarray(output_array)
output_image.save( output_path )

I have also tried this code but it did not solve the problem
input_img = cv2.imread( input_path )
output = remove(input_img)
cv2.imwrite( output_path, output )

This is one of the photos that I want to remove the background from

this is result of my code

and this is result remove.bg

how can i get a result such as remove.bg?

file an issue with rembg. -- what do you mean, "your code"? you call remove(), which is surely just using rembg, right?

@ChristophRackwitz In short, I have to say yes.  I'm just calling remove, but if I wanted to give a complete answer, I'd say my code is a bit more complicated than what I've written.  Actually, I am not a python programmer and I make all the changes I need in php and from php I call this python script to remove the background.

so your issue is with... the rembg website doing something different from their rembg python module? that is something you should file as an issue on their github https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg
